# HTML тэг <a> в режиме display: block вертикальное выравнивание содержимого

Tags: html, css, button

Дорогие уважаемые специалисты, помогите с вопросом не могу разобраться, делаю кнопку из тега `<a>`, хочу выравнять её вертикально по центру, чтобы задать ей высоту устанавливаю её в режиме `display: inline-block;`, но как только добавляю ей высоту например `height: 35px;` то всё её содержимое смещается наверх, независимо от того какой параметр указать в `vertical-align: middle;` Как выровнять её вертикально по центру? Будьте добры помогите, работа простаивает.

```css
.button_box {
 background: #507299;
 height: 55px;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle; 
}

.button_text {
  color: #fff;
}

.button_block {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_box">
  <a href="" class="button_block">
    <span class="box_button_icon"><img src="https://vop0.ru/template/bmp/7user.png" width="15" height="15" alt="Мои вопросы"></span>
    <span class="button_text">Мои вопросы</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Вот мой код в jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nrvobf5j/1/

Comment: vertical-align работает только для inline и inline-block в вашем случае надо использовать либо padding либо flex и да наверно в 2018 - 2019 году лучше использовать svg в качестве иконок либо иконочный шрифт

Comment: @oooo благодарю за помощь, у меня `inline-block`, как выровнять? Если не получится воспользуюсь `padding`

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов [ВОТ ТАК](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/RedNwX) наверно

Comment: @НикитаФаст Да, огромное спасибо, если flex будет плохо работать воспользуюсь вашим решением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проще всего наверное через flex:

```css
.button_block{
display:inline-flex;
height:60px;
padding:20px 50px;
background-color:red;
align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_box">
  <a href="" class="button_block">
<span class="box_button_icon"><img src="https://vop0.ru/template/bmp/7user.png" width="15" height="15" alt="Мои вопросы"></span>
<span class="button_text">Мои вопросы</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что надо

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов по моей ссылке тоже самое .....только флекс там не нужен

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы изменить размер отступов используйте **[padding](http://htmlbook.ru/css/padding)**:

```css
.button_box {
  background: #507299;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 50px;
}

.button_text {
  color: #fff;
}

.button_block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_box">
  <a href="" class="button_block">
    <span class="box_button_icon"><img src="https://vop0.ru/template/bmp/7user.png" width="15" height="15" alt="Мои вопросы"></span>
    <span class="button_text">Мои вопросы</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, padding тоже выход.